# I want to use two template engines in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, templates

I am using velocity engine in my current spring boot project.
I'm trying to switch to vue.js from next time, but it seems difficult to switch all at once.
Can two templates coexist per page?

two template engine in one project

Comment: Vue.js is client side so you still have 1 template engine on the backend side.